# CORS blocking POST http token call on nginx

Tags: symfony, nginx, ionic-framework, cors, xmlhttprequest

I have a local nginx server runing on a macOS (M2) on **localhost:80** and I'm trying to connect an Ionic 5 app running on **localhost:8100**

brew services running:

```
mysql       ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
nginx       ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist                 
php@7.3     ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php@7.3.plist
```

At first, every call to the api was blocked by cors. it's fixed now with this **nginx.conf**

```
http {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:8100'; #The Ionic app IP
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, Authorization';
  
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /opt/homebrew/var/www/mySymfony3Api/public; #Server path
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:8100';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'content-type, Authorization';

    location / {
      [...]
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:8100';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, Authorization';
    }
  }

}
```

and this is the endpoint in security.yaml

```
security:
  firewalls:
    oauth_token:
      pattern: ^/oauth/v2/token
      fos_oauth: true
      stateless: true
      anonymous: true
```

and now some GET api calls are currently working. (I know I maybe overextended there but it works)

The issue becomes when trying to call the token generation endpoint:

http://localhost/oauth/v2/token

If I call it from postman it works, even if I call it trough the terminal using curl

```
curl --location 'http://localhost/oauth/v2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "grant_type":"password",
  "username":"myUser@myDomain.com",
  "password":"myPassword",
  "client_id":"aValidClientID",
  "client_secret":"aValidClientSecret"
}'
```

this is working fine, but using any browser even with extensions to disable CORS (just in case) the request is blocked.

This is the request that fails

```
Request URL: http://localhost/oauth/v2/token
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

- Request Headers - 
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
sec-ch-ua: "Brave";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

And this is the error that shows the console:

```
login:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/oauth/v2/token' from origin
'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request
doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

This is an example of a request that actually works:

```
Request URL: http://localhost/api/establishment_types
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

- Response Headers -
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.23.3
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.33
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Thu, 23 Mar 2023 12:44:17 GMT
X-Debug-Token: 53f151
X-Debug-Token-Link: http://localhost/_profiler/53f151
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8100
access-control-allow-methods: PUT, GET, HEAD, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true

- Request Headers -
GET /api/establishment_types HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost
Origin: http://localhost:8100
Referer: http://localhost:8100/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-GPC: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Brave";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
```

Any idea of what can I do? Im trying everything with no results

Answer (score 0):

Non-200 responses must also be handled accordingly with `always`, which ensures that browsers will always receive the correct response headers for all CORS requests. In `server` block:

**config**

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
server {
  listen 888;

  # Headers will be removed if location {} adds headers there
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * always;

  # Immediately satisfy CORS requests - above CORS headers are included
  if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    return 200;
  }
}
```

**tests**

```bash
$ curl -I -X OPTIONS localhost:888/   # ✅ 200
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

$ curl -I -X GET localhost:888/       # ✅ 404
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: where should I put that? in the nginx.conf replacing the ``add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:8100';`` line?

Comment: Above tests originate from `nginx.conf` file. Use `$ nginx -t && nginx -s reload` to test.

Comment: seems like I can get the token now by placing your code over ``http { server { location / {`` also I had to add ``add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Content-Type'`` but now its blocking the following calls with a 401 status (unauthorized) because I think its blocking the authorization calls with the token. any idea?